# Can I delete my original gmail account associated with my android & use my other gmail address

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, android-versions

I originally set up my android with my original gmail account. I've since added a second gmail account & I'd like to switch my android over to the second account without repercussions. I'd eventually like to delete the initial gmail account, as that address is no longer useful.

Answer (score -1):

First off there is no way to not have repercussions if you do this.

You can delete an account by using your computer but be warned if you have purchased any games, music, movies, etc. these items will no longer be available to you with out dishing out extra funds as those purchases were bought from your original account and you'll need to buy them again. And any apps you have on your phone may not function correctly let alone at all if you do.

If you wish to continue goto

https://myaccount.google.com

Sign in (if needed)

Scroll down to the bottom of the page and click "Delete Google Account and Data" and follow the prompts to compleatly remove the account in question.

And a little FYI be sure to set up 2-Step verification for your accounts as it will help protect your accounts from unwanted entities from looking at, reading and or a complete takeover of yor accounts. You would get a text from them with a 6 digit code to set up a computer as a trusted one. Someone I know almost was one of the unfortunate ones on this matter.

Comment: I've completed removed a Google account from my phones before without losing the apps etc. bought with that account.